# Getting data from Sharepoint to another server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently working on a mobile concept.
We are running a Sharepoint 2010 Intranet solution, which is ONLY accessible within the company.

We want to make a mobile solution (for people outside), with data from the Sharepoint server.
I would like to have the data moved i.e. every 10-15 minutes through a cron job, and then move the data to an external database, which the mobile solution can access.

What is the easiest way to move the data? Using the web services, or are there any other ways to do this?

Thank you on beforehand,

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to code a timer job, which is a cron job scheduled by sharepoint that you can set to run every night with some Sharepoint Object model code that extracts all the data and sends it to the other server, you can do this using ado.net or any equivalent technology like ORMS etc, so this method pushes the data to the server.

If you have limitations on the connectivity like firewalls that only allow http traffic then definitely you will need to use either web services or the client object model, this method pulls the data from the server.

Client Object Model is preferred over web services as it among other features it batches the requests to make it more efficient, the api is better to manipulate data, etc.

Another option is to use SSIS to do the job as described in this artice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx

Comment: Thank you! A lot of different methods. 
A small additional question;
I have been looking closer in to the different solutions, but which one is best for getting pages transferred? It is mainly the articles on our site, which we want to extract from the SharePoint server.
Which solution would you prefer for that?

Again, thank you for your help so far.
Jens

Comment: When you say pages, when kind of pages you are talking about? publishing pages?

Comment: Yep. Publishing pages, with added information like title, author, etc.

Comment: Publishing Pages are just List Items supported by Page Layouts for rendering. So all you need to do is to copy the lists items across and have the proper page layouts installed and enabled in the target site.